# About an inequality that looks obvious.

Tags: inequality

My question is:

Prove or disprove:
$$
a_1,a_2,...,a_n\;\text{ and }\;b_1,b_2,...,b_n\;\text{ are positive real numbers }(n\geq 2)
$$
Then if $a_1a_2...a_n=b_1b_2,...,b_n$ and $\min(a_i) \leq \min(b_i),\max(a_i)\geq \max(b_i)$

We can conclude that $a_1+a_2+...+a_n \geq b_1+b_2+...+b_n$?

I used to think this as an obvious result, since the AM is greater if the sequence is more discrete when the GM is fixed.

However, today I tried to prove it, or find an counter-example, both ways failed.

The only way I tried is to raise both sides to the $n^{th}$ power, and try to factor the difference, however it does not go well.

Then I just ran out of way to deal with it. Any help or hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is false: see $1,2,2$ and $1,4,1$.

Comment: @Mindlack you are right, I guess it will need more conditons. Do you think $max(a_i) \geq max(b_i)$ willl work?

Comment: No, same counterexample (reverse them of course). You could try and look at this, though: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata's_inequality

Comment: @Mindlack actually the original statement is $a\leq b\leq c\leq d\leq e\leq f$,and that  $adf=bce$, that is the original one, sorry I should type it.

Comment: @Mindlack I am going to check this, but I think same counter example will not work.

Comment: Apply Karamata with the logarithms of your variables, then.

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you, that is a great idea.

Comment: @Mindlack Sorry, I tried to use Karamata,with function $f(x)=-ln(x)$ which is convex, but still don't know how to prove this...

Comment: Use Karamata on the variables $\ln{a},\ln{b}$ ... with the $\exp$ function.

Comment: @Mindlack I mean, using Karamata is a great way to solve the original qustion, but the generalize form,which I wrote(with fixed conditions). Is that true? I don't know how to use Karamata with that one.

Comment: I am sorry, I had misread your question. It is no, check with $0.5,2,2,10$ and $0.5,1,4,10$.

Comment: @Mindlack Right, that is a wrong statement! Thank you.